# C++ segmentation fault 11 while using template

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I just got started on c++ templates, in which I am creating a template square function, a template MyVector Class and overriding the multiplication operator for my MyVector class.

I am facing an issue in the part where i am squaring the MyVector object, i.e. square(bv) where its failing with a segmentation fault 11.
Any help or pointers are welcome.

I am on Mac OS, compiling with g++

> Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
>   Thread model: posix

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T square(T x){
    return x*x;
}
//Template has a side effect of code bloat, 
//i.e. both the datatypes will have a different code sections
//Template Class
template <typename T>
class MyVector{
    T arr[100];
    int size;
public:
    MyVector():size(0){}
    void push(T x){ arr[size]=x; size++;}
    T get(int i) const {return arr[i];}
    int getSize() const { return size;}
    void print() const { for(int i=0;i<size;i++){cout<<arr[i]<<endl;}}
};
//Template Operator multiply for MyVector
template <typename T>
MyVector<T> operator* (const MyVector<T>& rhs1, MyVector<T>& rhs2){
    MyVector<T> ret;
    for(int i=0; rhs1.getSize();i++){
        ret.push(rhs1.get(i)*rhs2.get(i));
    }
    cout<<"In BV Squared"<<endl;
    ret.print();
    return ret;
};
int main(){
    // cout<<square(5)<<endl;
    // cout<<square(5.5)<<endl;
    cout<<square<int>(5)<<endl;
    cout<<square<double>(5.5)<<endl;
    MyVector<int> bv;
    bv.push(1);
    bv.push(2);
    bv.push(8);
    bv.push(9);
    bv.print();

    cout<<"Squared bv:"<<endl;
    bv = square(bv);
    bv.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: what line is it segfaulting on? Have you tried using a debugger to help you find the condition that it is segfaulting on?

Comment: Not the cause of the segfault but your square function takes its argument by *value* which it probably shouldn't (you're needlessly making a copy of the parameter)

Comment: yah, its segfaulting on the square(bv) part, and yes i tried debugging it, but i am still getting used to xcode, coming from visual studio.

Comment: `for(int i=0; rhs1.getSize();i++)` What do you think this is doing?

Comment: `for(int i=0; rhs1.getSize();i++){` that middle part should be `i < rhs1.getSize();` you're currently looping forever

Comment: @n.m this is getting the size from MyVector..

Comment: s**t, cant believe it, thats so silly of me...

Comment: sorry guys for wasting your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop invariant inside the function template `MyVector<T> operator* (const MyVector<T>& rhs1, MyVector<T>& rhs2)` is incorrect. Change

```
for(int i=0; rhs1.getSize();i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < rhs1.getSize();i++)
             ^^^^
```

Comment: thanks and sorry, i let the complexity of the problem get better of me. That was a really basic stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: @vhora Enough apologies, finding little mistakes is rather unlikely to make you feel clever ;) Happens all the time.